# Which part of the Javascript Promise function is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm learning Javascript async programming and Promise. I have the following code.

```
let promiseTest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
console.log("Inside Promise");
resolve('Promise is resolved'); 
});

console.log("Before Promise"); 
promiseTest().then((data) => { console.log(data); });
console.log("After Promise");
```

I have the function "promiseTest". I want to execute that asynchronously. In real world scenario, it could be a function that fetch the web service or query the database. I was expecting to have the following result from the code.

```
Before Promise
After Promise
Inside Promise
Promise is resolved
```

I was expecting that "console.log(" Inside Promise") " will be executed asynchronously since it is inside the Promise function. But the actual result is

```
Before Promise
Inside Promise
After Promise
Promise is resolved
```

As you see tin the actual result, Inside Promise is executed synchronously and blocking the main thread. Only the code inside "resolve" is asynchronous. Maybe, my current understanding of javascript Promise is incorrect. How do I modify my existing code to make sure the whole function " promiseTest " is executed asynchronously without blocking the main thread.

Comment: Note that even the delayed part will block the main thread. The only way to not block the main thread is to use an other thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executor function is executed synchronously. Promise doesn't make any code asynchronous; its just a mechanism to get notified when something, that is already asynchronous, has completed.

If you want to make a API call, that is already asynchronous and if you use the fetch API, then you don't need the promise constructor because `fetch(...)` already returns a promise.

> Only the code inside "resolve" is asynchronous

In your code, `resolve()` function is also called synchronously; only the callback function of `promiseTest().then(..)` is invoked asynchronously.

> How do I modify my existing code to make sure the whole function
> "promiseTest" is executed asynchronously without blocking the main
> thread.

You will have to use another [thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Even if you delay the execution of the `promiseTest` function using `setTimeout`, once it is pushed in the call stack, it will execute synchronously. Nothing else will execute when the delayed `promiseTest` function is being executed.

If delaying the execution is what you want, just wrap the `promiseTest` function call in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, promise doesn't make the function async. There would be async calls inside that promise function and what promise provide is the mechanism to notify back to the caller ( with resolve, reject ) once those async calls are complete. Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Promise is a wrapper around the already asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for your promiseTest function, this will give you the expected result.

`setTimeout` sets a timer which executes a function once the timer expires.

As you can see "After Promise" will be logged before "Promise is resolved", this is entirely expected, since the promise will take some time (in this case 1000 milliseconds) to resolve.

```js
let promiseTest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Inside Promise"); 
        resolve('Promise is resolved');
    }, 1000) 
});

console.log("Before Promise"); 
promiseTest().then((data) => { console.log(data); });
console.log("After Promise");
```

Comment: They want "Inside Promise" to execute later, here you have about the same result as them, except that a full event-loop loop occurred before the then callback gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I just noticed a trick that I can put my whole block code inside setTimeout to put a function to execute later.